# Geting back transferred Bitcoins when the opposite party denied to accept the transfer

Tags: transactions

I have sent some bitcoins to Payza Account, but Payza denied the transaction saying that the transfer shall be made through "Add Funds".    Now the Bitcoins are not showing either in my Bitcoins account or Payza Account.

How can I getback those bitcoins into my Bitcoins Account.

Comment: If you've sent money to Payza there are just two options: either you figure it out with Payza, or you sue them to have a third party force them to figure it out with you. There is no mechanism for anyone else to get involved provided by Bitcoin.

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet would be to contact their support and see if they can help.

Bitcoin transactions can't be "cancelled" or "refunded" after they get confirmed. Only the person that owns the address that you sent your BTC to will be able to send you your coins back.